# Why am I getting an xml error in my javafx project?

Tags: xml, javafx

I have an onAction Error in my JavaFX project. I am using XML for the styling and handling of actions. The weird thing is this is one of 3 controllers in the project, the other 2 seem to work fine. Makes me think its something with the xml?

I have looked at previous questions similar to this problem and it seems a java.event.ActionEvent was the fix, but as you can see I have included that package.

In the eclipse IDE an error symbol is present at the line
    Button fx:id="cameraPortClear"

The error underlined is onAction="resetCameraPortFields"

The controller code

```
package application;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

public class LaunchPadSystemsController {

private String cameraPort1 = null;
private String cameraPort2 = null;

@FXML
private TextField cameraPort1Field;

@FXML
private TextField cameraPort2Field;

@FXML
private Button cameraPortEnter;

@FXML 
private Button cameraPortClear;

private boolean cameraPortStatus() {
    if(cameraPort1.isEmpty() | cameraPort2.isEmpty())
        return false;

    else if(!(cameraPort1.isEmpty()) & !(cameraPort2.isEmpty()))
        return true;

    else 
        return false;
}

private void setCameraPortFields(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("yeeetd");

    this.cameraPort1 = cameraPort1Field.getText();
    this.cameraPort2 = cameraPort2Field.getText();

    System.out.println(cameraPort1);
    System.out.println(cameraPort2);

}


private void resetCameraPortFields(){

    cameraPort1Field.setText("");
    cameraPort2Field.setText("");
}

}
```

The XML code (The button tag is last few lines)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.Double?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane?> 
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Line?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" 
prefHeight="1023.0" prefWidth="1612.0" style="-fx-background-color: BLACK;" 
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
fx:controller="application.LaunchPadSystemsController">
   <children>
      <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="504.0" prefHeight="101.0" prefWidth="573.0" text="Launch Pad Systems" textFill="#f2cd16" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="922.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="504.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="535.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
     <font>
        <Font name="Cooper Black" size="36.0" />
     </font>
  </Label>
  <GridPane layoutX="4.0" layoutY="103.0" prefHeight="923.0" prefWidth="597.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="4.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="1011.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="100.0">
    <columnConstraints>
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
    </columnConstraints>
    <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints maxHeight="437.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="437.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints maxHeight="502.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="437.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    </rowConstraints>
     <children>
        <TitledPane alignment="CENTER" animated="false" prefHeight="765.0" prefWidth="597.0" text="Camera 1 Feed">
          <content>
            <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
          </content>
           <font>
              <Font name="Cooper Black" size="14.0" />
           </font>
        </TitledPane>
        <TitledPane alignment="CENTER" animated="false" prefHeight="754.0" prefWidth="597.0" text="Camera 2 Feed" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
          <content>
            <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="453.0" prefWidth="595.0" />
          </content>
           <font>
              <Font name="Cooper Black" size="14.0" />
           </font>
        </TitledPane>
     </children>
  </GridPane>
  <Pane layoutX="597.0" layoutY="99.0" prefHeight="924.0" prefWidth="1017.0" style="-fx-background-color: GREY;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="100.0">
     <children>
        <ImageView fitHeight="252.0" fitWidth="844.0" layoutX="450.0" layoutY="302.0" rotate="90.0">
           <image>
              <Image url="@../../../Desktop/bigchung.png" />
           </image>
        </ImageView>
        <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="DODGERBLUE" height="179.0" layoutX="42.0" layoutY="695.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="85.0" />
        <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="42.0" layoutY="776.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="85.0" text="N2O">
           <font>
              <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
           </font>
        </Label>
        <Polygon fill="RED" layoutX="301.0" layoutY="657.0" rotate="90.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" style="-fx-scale-x: .3; -fx-scale-y: .3;">
          <points>
            <Double fx:value="-50.0" />
            <Double fx:value="40.0" />
            <Double fx:value="50.0" />
            <Double fx:value="40.0" />
            <Double fx:value="0.0" />
            <Double fx:value="-60.0" />
          </points>
        </Polygon>
        <Polygon fill="RED" layoutX="330.0" layoutY="657.0" rotate="-90.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" style="-fx-scale-x: .3; -fx-scale-y: .3;">
           <points>
              <Double fx:value="-50.0" />
              <Double fx:value="40.0" />
              <Double fx:value="50.0" />
              <Double fx:value="40.0" />
              <Double fx:value="0.0" />
              <Double fx:value="-60.0" />
           </points>
        </Polygon>
        <Polygon fill="RED" layoutX="418.0" layoutY="656.0" rotate="90.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" style="-fx-scale-x: .3; -fx-scale-y: .3;">
           <points>
              <Double fx:value="-50.0" />
              <Double fx:value="40.0" />
              <Double fx:value="50.0" />
              <Double fx:value="40.0" />
              <Double fx:value="0.0" />
              <Double fx:value="-60.0" />
           </points>
        </Polygon>
        <Polygon fill="RED" layoutX="447.0" layoutY="656.0" rotate="-90.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" style="-fx-scale-x: .3; -fx-scale-y: .3;">
           <points>
              <Double fx:value="-50.0" />
              <Double fx:value="40.0" />
              <Double fx:value="50.0" />
              <Double fx:value="40.0" />
              <Double fx:value="0.0" />
              <Double fx:value="-60.0" />
           </points>
        </Polygon>
        <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="286.0" layoutY="665.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="60.0" text="Fill Soln.">
           <font>
              <Font name="System Bold" size="10.0" />
           </font>
        </Label>
        <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="404.0" layoutY="665.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="60.0" text="Dump Soln.">
           <font>
              <Font name="System Bold" size="10.0" />
           </font>
        </Label>
        <Line endX="101.0" layoutX="183.0" layoutY="647.0" startX="-97.0" stroke="RED" strokeWidth="5.0" />
        <Line endX="-101.5" endY="151.0" layoutX="186.0" layoutY="544.0" startX="-100.5" startY="103.0" stroke="RED" strokeWidth="5.0" />
        <Line endX="184.0" endY="-4.0" layoutX="736.0" layoutY="803.0" startX="184.0" startY="18.0" stroke="GREEN" strokeWidth="3.0" />
        <Line endX="184.0" endY="-12.0" layoutX="746.0" layoutY="813.0" startX="184.0" startY="20.5" stroke="RED" strokeWidth="5.0" />
        <Line endX="183.0" endY="-14.0" layoutX="747.0" layoutY="848.0" startX="-247.5" startY="-14.0" stroke="RED" strokeWidth="5.0" />
        <Line endX="163.0" endY="-34.5" layoutX="757.0" layoutY="858.0" startX="-240.5" startY="-34.5" stroke="GREEN" strokeWidth="3.0" />
        <Line endX="21.0" endY="280.5" layoutX="478.0" layoutY="553.0" startX="21.0" startY="94.5" stroke="RED" strokeWidth="5.0" />
        <Line endX="-5.0" endY="53.0" layoutX="504.0" layoutY="594.0" startX="-42.0" startY="53.0" stroke="RED" strokeWidth="5.0" />
        <Line endX="17.0" endY="26.0" layoutX="384.0" layoutY="620.0" startX="-37.0" startY="27.0" stroke="RED" strokeWidth="5.0" />
        <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#f2cd16" height="55.0" layoutX="264.0" layoutY="428.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="102.0" />
        <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#f2cd16" height="55.0" layoutX="265.0" layoutY="337.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="102.0" />
        <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="269.0" layoutY="356.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="95.0" text="GSE" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true">
           <font>
              <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
           </font>
        </Label>
        <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="283.0" layoutY="447.0" text="Relay Board" textAlignment="CENTER">
           <font>
              <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
           </font>
        </Label>
        <Line endX="-200.0" endY="36.0" layoutX="516.0" layoutY="392.0" startX="-200.0" />
        <Line endX="-110.0" endY="382.0" layoutX="425.0" layoutY="265.0" startX="-135.0" startY="218.0" />
        <Line endX="-83.0" endY="121.0" layoutX="516.0" layoutY="525.0" startX="-179.0" startY="-42.0" />
        <Line endX="-140.0" endY="-96.0" layoutX="656.0" layoutY="554.0" startX="-140.0" startY="269.0" stroke="GREEN" strokeWidth="3.0" />
        <Line endY="-0.5" layoutX="516.0" layoutY="456.0" startX="-150.0" startY="-0.5" stroke="GREEN" strokeWidth="3.0" />
     </children>
  </Pane>
  <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="129.0" text="Camera 1 Port: " textFill="WHITE" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="2.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="10.0">
     <font>
        <Font name="Cooper Black" size="14.0" />
     </font>
  </Label>
  <Label layoutY="34.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="129.0" text="Camera 2 Port: " textFill="WHITE" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="2.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="44.0">
     <font>
        <Font name="Cooper Black" size="14.0" />
     </font>
  </Label>
  <TextField fx:id="cameraPort1Field" layoutX="119.0" layoutY="6.0" />
  <TextField fx:id="cameraPort2Field" layoutX="119.0" layoutY="43.0" />
  <Button fx:id="cameraPortEnter" layoutX="295.0" layoutY="6.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="149.0" text="Enter">
     <font>
        <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
     </font>
  </Button>
  <Button fx:id="cameraPortClear" layoutX="295.0" layoutY="40.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="resetCameraPortFields" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="149.0" text="Clear">
     <font>
        <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
     </font>
  </Button>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Error Message

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: Error resolving onAction='resetCameraPortFields', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script.
/C:/Users/Blake%20Patterson/eclipse- 
workspace/TelemetryGui/bin/LaunchPadXML.fxml:166

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2597)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$100(FXMLLoader.java:103)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processEventHandlerAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:610)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:770)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2823)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2532)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
```

Comment: What is the error message? We can’t help you without that critical detail.

Comment: Edited to include message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `onAction` attribute is incorrectly specified. To reference a method in the controller, you need to prefix it with `#`:

```xml
<Button fx:id="cameraPortClear" ... onAction="#resetCameraPortFields" ... >
```

Additionally, your `resetCameraPortFields()` method is `private`. You either need to annotate it `@FXML`:

```
@FXML
private void resetCameraPortFields(){

    cameraPort1Field.setText("");
    cameraPort2Field.setText("");
}
```

or change its accessibility to `public`.

Comment: You know I knew that and I have no idea why I did not implement that. The annotation with adding the # to the xml worked. All the other controllers have private methods and work fine but ill keep that in mind. Thanks.